# PDF of maximum of two random variables

Tags: probability, random

X and Y have joint PDF

$$\ f_{X,Y}(x,y) =\begin{cases}
        1/15 & 0\le x \le 5, & 0 \le y \le 3 \\
       0 & \text{otherwise.} \\
        \end{cases}
$$

Find the PDF of $W = max(X,Y)$.

I try to solve this but I do not know the answer

please check my solution.

CDF :
$$\ P(W \le w) = \begin{cases}
   1  & 4 \le w \le 5\\
   w/3 & 1 \le w \le 3\\
   0  &  w \le 0 \end{cases}$$

PDF :
$$\ P(W \le w) = \begin{cases}
   0  & 4 \le w \le 5\\
   1/3 & 1 \le w \le 3\\
   0  &  w \le 0 \end{cases}$$

Comment: It is not correct. Hint: $f_X = \frac15 \chi_{[0,5]}$, $f_Y = \frac13 \chi_{[0,3]}$, and $f_{X,Y} = f_X f_Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we can write the joint density $f_{X,Y}$ in the form $f_Xf_Y$ where $f_X = \frac15\sf 1_{[0,5]}$ and $f_Y=\frac13\sf1_{[0,3]}$, it follows that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $X\sim\sf U(0,5)$, $Y\sim\sf U(0,3)$. If $W=X\vee Y$ then for any $w\geqslant 0$, $$\{W\leqslant w\}=\{X\leqslant w\}\cap\{Y\leqslant w\}, $$
so by independence,
\begin{align}
F_W(w):&=\mathbb P(W\leqslant w)\\
&= \mathbb P(\{X\leqslant w\}\cap\{Y\leqslant w\})\\
&= \mathbb P(X\leqslant w)\mathbb P(Y\leqslant w)\\
&= F_X(w)F_Y(w).
\end{align}
Differentiating, we have the density of $W$ as
\begin{align}
f_W(w) &= \frac{\sf d}{\sf dw}F_W(w)\\ 
&= f_X(w)F_Y(w) + F_X(w)f_Y(w)\\
&= \frac15\sf 1_{[0,5]}(w)\left(\int_0^{w\wedge 3}f_Y(y)\ \mathsf dy\right) + \left(\int_0^{w\wedge 5} f_X(x)\ \sf dx \right)\frac13\sf 1_{[0,3]}(w)\\
&= \frac15\sf 1_{[0,5]}(w)\left(\frac{(w\wedge 3)}{3}\right) +\left(\frac{w\wedge 5}5 \right)\frac13\sf 1_{[0,3]}(w)\\
&= \frac2{15}w\sf 1_{[0,3]}(w) + \frac15\sf 1_{[3,5]}(w).
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks @joriki, I gain a strange satisfaction from typing LaTeX. Don't ask me to explain it...

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I have question about notation.
What is the meaning of 1_[0,5] ?

Comment: $\sf 1$ denotes the indicator function, e.g. $\sf 1_{[0,5]}(w)=1$ if $w\in[0,5]$ and $0$ if $w\notin[0,5]$.

Comment: I have one more question about notation. What is the meaning of ^ and inverse of (^).

Comment: $a\wedge b=\min\{a,b\}$ and $a\vee b=\max\{a,b\}$.